# How could I convert a function such that $f(r,\theta )=r^5(\cos\theta)$ back into the cartesian coordinate

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

Would this just be $f(x,y) = x(x^2 +y^2)^2 $? What is the difference between in converting an equation such as $r = r\cos(\theta )$ and a function such as $f(x)=r\cos(\theta )$?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! I don't understand your question. The function in the title uses polar coordinates.

Comment: Can you explain how you are defining r in terms of itself and theta, did you mean $f(r,\theta)$

Comment: Yes, $f(x,y)=x(x^2+y^2)^2$

Comment: To clarify, I was just given this function f(r,(θ)=(cos((θ))*r^5, and it is in the polar coordinate, so  I guess the r just mean radius and θ be the angle as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems confusing because $f(r,\theta)= r^5 \cos(\theta)$ is already in the polar form.
However $r= \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\cos(\theta)$= $\frac {x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ which would mean$$(x^2+y^2)^{5/2}\times\frac {x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=x(x^2+y^2)^{2}.$$

So $r^5cos(\theta) = x(x^2+y^2)^{2}$.

Resolving $r$ along $x$ and $y$ directions yields $r\cos(\theta)$ and $r\sin(\theta)$ respectively.